# A Novel Based Off A Song...How Close Can It Get?

Tags: creative-writing, copyright, music

I have recently become obsessed with the song Devil Town by Cavetown. I haven't been that into writing recently and this song has really inspired me. I was wondering what's a yes and whats a no to what can/can't be included? (Also, Would I Be Able To Use "Devil Town" As The Title?)

Answer (score 0):

Questions about citing song titles or song lyrics have been asked before (use the site search to find them). The consensus is that you should not cite song lyrics without written consent of the copyright holder while you may use the song title within your text. Do not use the song title as the title of your book, though.

As for how close you can base your story on the story in a song, I would say: Very close. But only if you do not mention the song in your book at all and do not use the same names.

My reasoning is the following:

1. A short story or novel is so much longer than a song that any story based on a song is (a) transformative and (b) very likely almost unrecognizable (if you do not use the names used in the song).
2. Inspiration is not a crime (but plagiarism may be: you can write a story about a school of wizards, but not one where the pupils play a ball sport riding on brooms).

The more generic the story in the song is (one of hundreds of murder ballads, for example), the more safe you are. The more uncommon the story of the song is ([a boy named Sue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_Named_Sue) whose dad left when he was three and left him a guitar etc.) and the closer you stick to the details of the orignal, the closer you come to breaking some law. If that is what you want to do, I would consult a lawyer.

---

This is not legal advice, and we are neither allowed nor qualified to give it. Also, the law is different in different jurisdictions.